# How we can get the docusign sigining_url same as link with the help of DocuSign_eSgin APIs. Which have all docusign option like stemp, signature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

When i am hitting   view_url = envelopes_api.create_recipient_view('YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID', response.envelope_id, recipient_view_request) it giving me url like
"https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/MTRedeem/v1....."
which does not have docusign attributes,
but email link start like "https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/?ti=6273ff8731f541...." which have docusign attributes options, like initials, stem, signature etc

```
def signed_document_view_url(envelope_id = nil)
 envelope_id = envelope_id || get_envelope_id
    return nil if envelope_id.nil?
    begin
      recipient_view_request = DocuSign_eSign::RecipientViewRequest.new
      recipient_view_request.return_url = @config[:return_url]
      recipient_view_request.authentication_method = 'None'
      recipient_view_request.email = @user.email
      recipient_view_request.user_name = @user.first_name
      view_url = envelope_api_obj.create_recipient_view(@config[:account_id], envelope_id, recipient_view_request)
      view_url[:url]
    rescue => e
      return nil
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your envelope does not have any tabs (signing elements, fields) then you get into a free-form mode where the signer can drag-and-drop tabs from the left to the document.

This is not related to [using an email vs](https://developers-beta.dev.docusign.net/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/). using [embedded signing](https://developers-beta.dev.docusign.net/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/).

So, if you want the signer to pick the tabs, all you have to do is not put them in the envelope, unrelated to what type of URL is used.